# JavaScript Passing retrieving and passing input info nodeValue vs createTextNode

Tags: javascript, appendchild, nodevalue, createtextnode

I've encountered something I believe is strange in JavaScript. I am building a form the idea of which is to provide the ability to add table rows and fields on demand. As you could imagine I started experimenting with `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc.

Why when I try to pass a value from an input field it cannot be appended directly and output to a `div` tag? However, when passing the retrieved value first through `createTextNode` and then outputting it works.

> The console says that the concatenation pat.appendChild(al) is not an
>   object

but `pat.appendChild(text)` works fine?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function appendTr (){

    var pat = document.createElement("p");
    /*var formValue = document.createTextNode("This works, but why doesn\'t the other one");
    p.appendChild(formValue);*/
    var al = document.getElementById("position").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(al);
    pat.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("outer").appendChild(pat);
}

</script>
<form>
    <table id="job">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="y1" name="y1" type="text"></td>
            <td><input id="y2" name="y2" type="text"></td>
            <td><input id="position" name="position" type="text"></td>
            <td><input id="org" name="org" type="text"></td>
            <td><input class="button" id="addRow" type="button" value="+" onclick="appendTr()"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<div id="outer">Not</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a Jsfiddle demonstrating the problem and tell us what browser you are using?  I am unable to replicate the 'pat.appendChild(al) is not an object' error you have described.

Answer (score 0):

`al` is a string and `text` is a node. The argument of `appendChild` has to be a node.

To output `al` directly into a div do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("outer").textContent=al;
```

Or when you want html-code in `al` to work:

```
document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML=al;
```